# Evitar concurrencia de jobs en jobs Multibranch con Inputs en Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

actualmente tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo un job de Jenkins (Multibranch) en el que el usaurio vía "Input" selecciona el nombre de la release a implantar

```
def userInput = input(
id: 'userInput', message: 'Rellenar los campos necesarios para poder lanzar el despliegue',
parameters: [string(name: 'nombreRelease', defaultValue: 'None', description: 'Nombre de la Release' )
```

Tengo que evitar que se ejecuten 2 jobs con el mismo valor de "nombreRelease". Es decir, que si ya hay uno en ejecución el segundo se aborte

¿Hay alguna funcionalidad en Jenkins que lo permita?

un saludo
Javi

Answer (score 0):

no me dí cuenta y cuando lanzo el job en paralelo, el segundo dice "Waiting for next available executor" por lo que no se pueden ejecutar a la vez.